# the probability distribution of dependent variables

Tags: statistics, probability, bayesian, probabilistic-programming, mcmc

There are three variables, `X3` is a function of `X1` and `X2`, `X2` also depends on `X1`.The dependency relationship is shown as the following graph.

[image]

In specific, `X3= f(X1, x2)` and `X2=g(X1)`. Therefore, `X3=f(X1, g(X1))`. If the probabilistic distribution of `X1` is known, how to get the probabilistic distribution of `X3`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell us what the distribution of x1 is and what f and g function are exactly? When f and g are simple, we can usually solve this analytically. But when the function is complex, this kind of problems are typically approximated by Monte Carlo simulation.